# Multiplication with different columns

Tags: r

```
A        B      C       D
a    -0.17   1.98   0.051
b     0.1    1.99   0.001
c    -0.2    0.245  0.003
d     0.25   0      2
```

I have a dataframe in which I have `B` column with - and + values, So in case of - values, I want to multiply its corresponding `C` and `D` column with (`-1`), hence my `C` and `D` respective rows will be *-ve*.

Then I want to multiply `B` columns each rows values with its consecutive `C` and `D` rows and a new down row with the sum of total `C` and `D`.

The final dataframe should look like this after the calculation.

```
A        B       C        D
a    -0.17  0.3366  0.00867
b     0.1   0.199   0.0001
c    -0.2   0.049   0.0006
d     0.25  0       0.5
            0.5846  0.50937
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the last 2 columns with the 'B' column, take the `abs`, assign it to those columns, and `rbind` the `colSums` of 'C' and 'D' to create the new row

```
df1[3:4] <- abs(df1[3:4] * df1[,2])
rbind(df1, c(A = NA, B= NA, colSums(df1[3:4])))
#     A     B      C       D
#1    a -0.17 0.3366 0.00867
#2    b  0.10 0.1990 0.00010
#3    c -0.20 0.0490 0.00060
#4    d  0.25 0.0000 0.50000
#5 <NA>    NA 0.5846 0.50937
```

#### Update

If the dataset is `data.table`,

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df1[, (3:4) := abs(.SD*B), .SDcols = 3:4]
rbind(df1, c(A= NA, B= NA, df1[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols = C:D]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), B = c(-0.17, 0.1, -0.2, 
0.25), C = c(1.98, 1.99, 0.245, 0), D = c(0.051, 0.001, 0.003, 
2)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: When I tried first command, it shows me, Error in Ops.data.frame(df1[3:4], df1[, 2]) : ‘*’ only defined for equally-sized data frames. Do you have suggestion regarding apply function

Comment: @Sandeep I copied only your dataset.  Is it a `matrix` or `data.frame`.  I assume it should be data.frame as it have different class columns.  I updated with the data I used

Comment: It is a dataframe, and I am using same code, but every time it is giving me same error.  abs function from which package?

Comment: @Sandeep Can u try it on the data from my post?  `abs` is from `base R`

Comment: Yup, yours is running perfectly. I checked class of my toy dataset. It says "datatbale", "dataframe". Original dataset has 100s more column like C and D. Thus, any help with any other function will be great

Comment: @Sandeep You should be updating your post with the `dput(yourtoydataset)`

Comment: @Sandeep UPdated the post